# Null pointer Exception for findFragmentById finding map view

Tags: android, google-maps

**What is happening::** I am not able to find the map view that returns this line `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mySupportMapId)`  as null

### CODE

***in onResume:***

```
FragmentManager fm=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mySupportMapId);
googleMap=smf.getMap();
```

***in xml***

```
 <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/rootJobsLocationId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/mySupportMapId"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="center" />

other code
```

### Error

smf becomes null

***note:*** i have a device that has google play services.... this error was not there when i was using regularfragment instead of support fragment

Comment: Check  `if (mMap == null)`

Comment: @MD Same guess. Need null checking

Comment: This behaviour is similar to http://www.coderanch.com/t/637421/Android/Mobile/getSupportFragmentManager-returns-null-devices ...but now i am seeing this in all devices ..... `googleMap==null` i checked , its true so it goes inside the condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/iqamah_map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

// Java code

```
    public class xxxx extends FragmentActivity {

   GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xxx);
map =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.iqamah_map)).getMap();

    }
}
```

Comment: My Activity is Extending FragmentActivity ....this is a wiered error i am facing !

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
    (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mySupportMapId)).getMap();
SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
googleMap = smf.getMap();
```

Instead of

```
    FragmentManager fm=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mySupportMapId);
googleMap=smf.getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your java file,

First of all YourActivity is Extending FragmentActivity or ActionBarActivity

put this code on Fragment java file onCreateView() method

```
    SupportMapFragment  googleMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
```

And also to destroy mapview on fragment,

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    SupportMapFragment suMapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
    if (suMapFrag != null)
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(suMapFrag ).commit();
}
```

I hope this code working fine... !!!